# Getting <<loop>> Exception in Haskell Depending on Pattern Arrangement

Tags: haskell

Someone can please explain why I am getting a loop in this code?

```
module Main where

import Data.List.Split
import Data.Maybe
import Text.Read

main :: IO ()
main = print (snd (toInmetDate "01/02/2012"))

type P a = (Bool, a)

readP :: (Read a) => String -> P a
readP text
  | isJust value    = (True, fromJust value)
  | isNothing value = (False, read "0")
  where value = readMaybe text

data InmetDate = InmetDate {dia :: P Int, mes :: P Int, ano :: P Integer}
  deriving (Show, Read)

toInmetDate :: String -> P InmetDate
toInmetDate x = if length l == 3
  then  (True, InmetDate (readP ds) (readP ms) (readP as))
  else  (False, InmetDate (False, 0) (False, 0) (False, 0))
  where (l,ds:ms:as:_) = (splitOn "/" x, l ++ replicate 20 "NULL")
```

I would state that, when I make:

```
  where (l,ds:ms:as:_) = (splitOn "/" x, l ++ replicate 20 "NULL")
```

equal to:

```
  where (ds:ms:as:_) = l ++ replicate 20 "NULL"
        l = splitOn "/" x
```

the code work perfectly.

Comment: Please, if downvoting, let me at last know why so I can figure what is wrong, thanks...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if I were in an unreasonable mood then I might have due to the code fragment not compiling (needs a few imports, a `main` for testing).

Comment: There appears to be a downvote on a lot of haskell questions lately.  Maybe someone is disgruntled and trying to demoralize the community.

Comment: Sad, I'm getting some more contact with Haskell after my first contact some years ago, and finding it a beautiful language, somewhat hard, but very beautiful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original, the value of `l` depends on a tuple that is recursively defined in terms of `l`. In the change, `l` depends solely on the value of `splitOn "/" x`.

Comment: The strictness of the pattern matching on the second element of the tuple can cause a lot of confusion.  For example, explicit laziness works `where (l,~(ds:ms:as:_)) = (splitOn "/" x, l ++ replicate 20 "NULL")`

Comment: After some more search about strictness I believe I finally understood it, I misunderstood haskell as a `lazy` instead of `non-strict` language

Comment: @RomuloPBenedetti, I'm glad you feel satisfied, but I feel like i need to point out that you probably don't understand it.  *lazy* and *non-strict* mean exactly the same thing as far as what output you will get (there is a [subtle distinction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7141537/33796) which doesn't matter here).  I think Thomas is right on, this is about the strictness of pattern matches.

Comment: You can read a little about lazy pattern matches [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_pattern_match) which might help, though I was unable to find an explanation I really liked.

Comment: Ok confuse, let me see it again...

So Haskell is not purely lazy, only purely non-strict, from outside to inside reduction, but, by what I understood now, non-strict evaluations don't need to be lazy computationally saying.

Now, the problem, by what I've understood [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_vs._non-strict): Is that pattern matching in particular is strict what forces non lazyness, because of some inplications you point on your link? Like avoiding patterns overlapping?